# Get prior date per person in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get a prior date for each row for each person (ID) in SQL Server 2008. I have several million rows. Example:

```
ID    TransactionDate

1 01/01/2012

1 01/20/2012

1 01/22/2012

2 01/20/2012

2 01/23/2012

2 01/25/2012
```

Returns:

```
ID    TransactionDate priorDate

1 01/01/2012  Null

1 01/20/2012  01/01/2012

1 01/22/2012  01/20/2012

2 01/20/2012 null

2 01/23/2012 01/20/2012

2 01/25/2012 01/23/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a `self join CTE (left)` with `row_number`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID, TransactionDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID order by TransactionDate )  AS RowNumber
   FROM table_name
)
SELECT a.ID,a.TransactionDate , aa.TransactionDate priorDate
FROM   CTE a
LEFT OUTER JOIN   CTE aa 
ON a.RowNumber = aa.RowNumber + 1
And aa.ID=a.ID
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1661/18)